# Android to esp8266 decryption

Tags: android, aes, arduino-esp8266

i used the aes library in android studio to encrypt a string of data to send to an esp8266 in AP mode. i am able to get the encrypted value but not the correct decrypted value. i am still particularly new to this and the decryption code was obtained through chatgpt.

this is the code i used to send an encrypted 16 byte value

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            byte[] key = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
                            String data = "thats my kung fu";
                            try {
                                SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
                                byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());

                                Log.d("EncryptedData", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT));

                                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                        .callTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                        .build();
                                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                                        .add("data", Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT))
                                        .build();
                                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url("http://192.168.4.1/post")
                                    .post(formBody)
                                    .build();
                            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                        String myResponse = response.body().string();
                                        Log.i("POST", myResponse);
                                        Log.d("TAG", "data: " + data);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("POST", "response code: " + response.code() + " response message: " + response.message());
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("TAG", "Post request failed");
                                }
                            });
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException |
                                     InvalidKeyException |
                                     IllegalBlockSizeException |
                                     BadPaddingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

i am able to receive the encrypted value on the esp, which is hYRPznVRiPVGVV0NkOy4XpVPZPLk6G6e7oLSAhZoSJk=

this is the arduino code to decrypt the value:

```
#include <AES.h>
#include <AESLib.h>
#include <AES_config.h>
#include <xbase64.h>

#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
AES aes;

const char* ssid = "ESP8266-AP";
const char* password = "password";

const byte key[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

void handlePost() {
  String val = server.arg("data");
  byte decrypted[val.length()];
  aes.set_key(key, sizeof(key));
  aes.decrypt((byte*)val.c_str(), decrypted); 
  String decryptedVal = String((char*)decrypted);
  Serial.println("Received value: " + decryptedVal);
  Serial.println("Encrypted value: " + val);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Value Received");
}


void setup() {
  //Set ESP as AP
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  //Initialize server
  server.begin();
  server.on("/post", HTTP_POST, handlePost);
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

this is my output:

Server started
Received value: *qz����5��2�k�D{`��?�3�?���?�j @`��?
Encrypted value: hYRPznVRiPVGVV0NkOy4XpVPZPLk6G6e7oLSAhZoSJk=

*received value is the supposedly decrypted value.

Comment: `i am able to receive the encrypted value on the esp, which is ` I think that is the base64 string of the encrypted data.

Comment: Can you first post the base64 string as it is sent? After that the base64 string as it is received?

Comment: `the decryption code was obtained through chatgpt.` Great! interesting! New times have come to stackoverflow.

Comment: `*received value is the supposedly decrypted value.` No. The received value should be a base64 string as that is what is sent.

Comment: the base64 string sent and received is the same. i checked it in the logcat of AS. the problem seems to be on the decryption side of the esp

Comment: Your post should contain both values  of base64 string. And also encrypted values displayed as hexadecimal. Only hexadecimal you can compare.

Comment: `Server started Received value: *qz����5��2�k�D{��?�3�?���?�j @��? ` Still confusing as that is no base64 and received is base64 by the esp(which happens to be the server). Confusing.

Comment: Can you decode and then decrypt the base64 on the Android app?

Comment: sorry what do you mean with the base64 and hexadecimals? im relatively new to all these haha. also i am able to decrypt the data properly in AS

Comment: Simple: you should show step by step what you have.

Comment: i managed to fix it. the problem was i encrypted then encoded the data before i sent it, but was decrypting then decrypting again. i had to decode then decrypt. however now i am left with some rubbish characters at the back of my decrypted string which i am still able to work with by just taking the first 16 characters and storing it in a new string